# Centos yum error: Failed to initialize NSS library - other fixes not working for me

Tags: centos, python, yum, rpm, nss

Basic issue from screenshot:

---

```
yum
error: Failed to initialize NSS library
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   cannot import name ts

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

---

I have looked at other articles and they all seem to reference getting a 'new' libnpsr4.so and doing an LD_PRELOAD.

However, I have downloaded many of these and have either copied them into my /usr/lib64 or simply tried to run them with the LD_PRELOAD and I can never get yum to fire again.  The error simply remains.

This started today after I simply ran yum update, accepted my changes (my normal behavior as a very novice linux user) and the system seemed to go on walkabout during the updates.  My SSH session timed out and upon re-connection, I now have this yum issue.  It also occurs with rpm.  I really do not want to rebuild this from scratch as it is a production system.

Here are some articles I have attempted to follow:

1. [yum/rpm Failed to initialize NSS library in chroot](https://serverfault.com/questions/911781/yum-rpm-failed-to-initialize-nss-library-in-chroot)
2. https://www.itechlounge.net/2017/09/linux-yumrpm-broken-upgrading-from-centosrhel-7-3-to-7-4-error-failed-to-initialize-nss-library/
3. https://www.kittell.net/code/red-hat-failed-to-initialize-nss-library/