# yum error: cannot import name ts

Tags: centos7, python, yum, rpm

We had a power hit to one of our servers during a yum update, and now trying to run yum produces the following:

```
# yum update
error: Failed to initialize NSS library

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

    cannot import name ts

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.5 (default, Aug 4 2017, 08:39:18)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

I can see that "ts" is in site-packages/rpm/transaction.py and that it's under python-2.7 (which matches the current python version). Has anyone seen this problem and found a workable fix?

---Update 1---

Got past this immediate error by rsyncing another, working system's site-packages directory, but am now getting a different error:

```
  /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/_rpm.so: undefined symbol: rpmtsAddReinstallElement
```

This one's proving harder to pin down.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/866294/error-failed-to-initialize-nss-library)?

Comment: I did. No joy, sadly. I'm close to the nuclear option; just building another VM and installing everything over again, then rsyncing over all the config and settings.

Comment: I received a similar error after removing a sqlite.so file. For whatever that's worth.